# Why result roadApi is different "how to get" on google.maps?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I try polyline snap to road  between two points on "road api". I have answer: "warningMessage:"Input path is too sparse. You should provide a path where consecutive points are closer to each other. Refer to the 'path' parameter in Google Roads API documentation.""

But if I do same at https://www.google.com.ua/maps/dir/%D0%94%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE,+%D0%94%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%8C%D0%B5,+%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/@48.1444745,34.1118762,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x40dbe303fd08468f:0xa1cf3d5f2c11aba!2m2!1d35.046183!2d48.464717!1m5!1m1!1s0x40dc673dfa85bb03:0x7e675cd9074d3f4a!2m2!1d35.139567!2d47.8388?hl=ru

Result is great, how I can do it like as  google.com/maps

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) instead of Roads API in order to get route between two points.

The request is something like

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%D0%94%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%94%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%2C%2049000&destination=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%8C%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%2C%2069061&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

You can also see this result in Directions calculator:

https://directionsdebug.firebaseapp.com/?origin=%D0%94%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%94%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%2C%2049000&destination=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%8C%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%2C%2069061

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, for calculator!